# Object that stores multidimensional index that can be supplied in operator[]

Tags: c++, c++23, mdspan

As C++23 supports multidimensional subscript operator(eg. `a[1, 2, 3]` and `mdspan`, is there native support for storing an multidimensional index as an object and used multiple times?

One example could be

```
// not storing as object {int a; double b;} due to layout considerations
// maybe we want contiguous accessing a/b individually to be fast but there are
// slow operations using both
std::array<std::array<std::array<int, L>, M>, N> a;
std::array<std::array<std::array<double,L>, M>, N> b;
// Index is conjured up
Index idx{3, 5, 2};
doSomething(a[idx], b[idx]);
```

Is there anything we would get from the mdspan library that achieve this? I feel this is actually something handy when doing operations above, but seems like we need to implement ourselves.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such type, but it should not be difficult to write a function that uses the values from a tuple to access a multidim subscript.

Comment: `std::mdspan`'s [`operator[]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/mdspan.mdspan.members#lib:operator%5b%5d,mdspan_) can take a `std::span` or `std::array`, but of course not all multidimensional array types may support this.